# Reading an integer number of SOCK_SEQPACKET messages from Unix Domain Socket

Tags: c, linux, unix-socket

I have two programs communicating via `AF_UNIX` `SOCK_SEQPACKET`'s. Process A is Producing the data and Process B is consuming it. I am using `POLL` in process B, and I want reading the data from the socket to be non-blocking. The messages Process A produces are variable length.

Let's assume process A produces some arbitrary number of messages very quickly before process B gets its `POLLIN` revent and wakes up to read from the socket.

What will happen if I call [`recv()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/recvmsg.2.html) in process B with the `MSG_DONTWAIT` flag and the buffer I pass isn't big enough to hold an integer number of messages? Will I get a `-1` return value with an `EWOULDBLOCK` errno? Or will the number of bytes for the integer number of messages I could extract be returned?